# How to manually remove left components in EaseUS?

Tags: components

I'm having trouble with the EaseUS software. Left components require the `EaseUS UPDATE SERVICE` while I can't find any in `Task Manager`. What should I do now?

Some screenshots of these errors:
[image: can't complete uninstall]

Comment: Do `Ctrl + Shift + Esc` and end the `EASEUS UPDATE SERVICE` if you find any, and try deleting again. Or Try restarting computer? Sometimes uninstall requires restart. If still this doesn't solve it, then maybe you have some other EaseUS software that's using the `UPDATE SERVICE`

Comment: Yeah, yesterday i uninstalled 3 apps of EaseUS but only 2 went wrong. Then I reinstall 2 apps and try deleting it again. I have a look in task manager but there is no EASEUS UPDATE SERVICE

Comment: Can you attach some screensnips of what exactly is the error, or anything else you consider worth showing?